# how to submit a form placed in datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, datatable

I am trying to submit data i shown in datatable form. The whole table which include the data placed in `<thead>` also. Let me ask in a more simple way with example.

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="val1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="checkBody" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" name="upload" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example").DataTable({
            "info": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "searching": false,
            "retrieve": true,
            "scrollY": "100%",
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is form and datatable works properly but the main problem is on clicking the submit button when i see `$_POST['val1']` value, its empty but the input field in tbody (`$_POST['checkBody']`) values can be display, why is it so ?
Note: the problem only occure when i use datatable but when i try it without datatable then no such problem occure and sorry for my bad english! and the real problem is complex but this is the small demo of the problem i facing.

Comment: when you submit form,  if you go to Network (dev tools and make sure you click checkbox "preserve log" and click on your POST request, in Header tab what are you seeing under Request payload (the bottom).

Comment: @AndrejsGubars bro! no error there

Comment: i'm not talking about errors, I am explaining you a way of inspecting data you are sending via POST using dev tools.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars bro i saw the request body it have this : val1=1&val1=&checkBody=&upload=save

Comment: @AndrejsGubars i shocked to see val two times but i am confuse why and how ? is it datatable clientside script magic or what ? i am too confuse ye. see the val1 variable have '1'  which is correct but after that & again that val store empty agh! why is it so ?

Comment: seems like your request body is not matching your provided question, where is val1?

Comment: val1 is an input name ye ! which become the POST array index after the submittion

Comment: Its' best to name your input in human understandable value, like name="description", name="title" and etc... try this.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars yeah usually i do that but it was just a demo and tho i found problem by learning the new technique of watching post variable in browser and the problem is datatable usually create the column(input tag etc) in header two times one in header second in body (hidden) with same name. so when we put something in the textfeild we see its usually the first one which is replaced by the second textfeild value (because both have same name) hense watching the request Body help me out to atleast know what the problem is! and now with an idea its easy for me to fix it. TY bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because datatable usually create the column(input tag etc) of header two times.

One in header second in body (hidden) with same 'name'. So when we put some value in the 'input'(textfeild) we see, its usually the first one, which is replaced by the second 'input'(textfeild) value (because both have same 'name' attribute).
 You can overcome this problem simply by using '[ ]' this infront of 'name' like

```
 <input type='text' name='val1[]' />
```

this will convert val1 into array so simply you can ignore the second one by using forloop and retrive `$_POST['val1']` first value. But Keep the ordering of datatable false.

Note: there maybe more easy way to solve this problem. if you know any, Post it !